# Indefinite integral of rational expression involving cubic polynomials

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I was given the following exercise:

> $$\int \frac{x^3}{(x^2+1)^3}dx$$

As a tip, my professor suggested using the following substitution: $t=x^2+1$.

Notice that if  $t=x^2+1$, then $x^2=t-1$ and therefore $x=(t-1)^\frac{1}{2}$. Then

$$x^3=x^2\cdot x=(t-1)(t-1)^\frac{1}{2}=(t-1)^\frac{3}{2}$$

and we have that

$$\int \frac{x^3}{(x^2+1)^3}dx=\int \frac{(t-1)^\frac{3}{2}}{t^3}dt.$$

But now that I have applied the suggested substitution, I don't really see how to continue with this integral. Integrating by parts doesn't seem to get me nowhere, and I can't seem to find any way to apply the substitution method. Am I missing something, or perhaps I made a mistake changing my integration variable from $x$ to $t=x^2+1$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you get rid of the $dx$, by the way?

Comment: Apparently I didn't get rid of it at all, as it was pointed out by Robert Z in his solution. Thanks Andrew!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot that, since $x=(t-1)^{\frac{1}{2}}$, we have also 
$$dx=D((t-1)^{\frac{1}{2}})\, dt=\frac{1}{2}(t-1)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\, dt.$$
Therefore, we find 
$$\int \frac{x^3}{(x^2+1)^3}dx=\int \frac{(t-1)^\frac{3}{2}}{t^3}\cdot
\color{blue}{\frac{1}{2}(t-1)^{-\frac{1}{2}}}\, dt=
\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{t-1}{t^3}\, dt=\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{dt}{t^2}-\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{dt}{t^3}.$$
Now it should be easy to finish the job.

Comment: Of course, I completely missed that. Thanks.

Comment: From $t = x^2 + 1$, it might be a bit simpler to use $dt = 2xdx \implies \frac{dt}{2} = xdx$, so $x^3dx = (x^2)xdx = (t - 1)\frac{dt}{2}$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan I agree, this is another way to consider the relationship between $dx$ and $dt$. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Partial integration may also work as follows:

\begin{eqnarray*} \int \frac{x^3}{(x^2+1)^3}dx
 & = & \int x^2\frac{x}{(x^2+1)^3}dx \\
& = & x^2\left(-\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{(x^2+1)^2}\right) + \frac{1}{4}\int \frac{2x}{(x^2+1)^2}dx \\
& = & -\frac{1}{4}\frac{x^2}{(x^2+1)^2} - \frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{x^2+1} (+C)
\end{eqnarray*}